# Why do titled matchstick burn with higher flame intensity?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

When we burn a matchstick when keeping it horizontal,  the flame get diffuse very quickly. However,  when we bend (lower) the tip of matchstick towards the ground , the intensity of the flame significantly increases? Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 2):

tilting the tip down causes the rising flame to effectively preheat the upper portions of the wooden stick, which makes it release combustible gases which add to the burning of the tip. This principle is actually used in some woodstove designs, in which the log to be burned is standing up vertically inside the stove and lit from the bottom.